# The method 'findRenderObject' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  ScrollController _sTabController;
  List<GlobalKey> keyList = <GlobalKey>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    keyList.clear();
    _sTabController = ScrollController();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      readyOfWidget();
    });
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
      keyList.add(GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'item_$i'));
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  void readyOfWidget() {
    for (int i = 0; i < keyList.length; i++) {
        RenderBox tabKeyItemRenderBox =
        keyList[i].currentContext.findRenderObject();
        if (tabKeyItemRenderBox != null) {
          Offset positionOfRenderBox =
          tabKeyItemRenderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
          print('keyItemRenderBox dx {$i}: ${positionOfRenderBox.dx}');
        }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        // height: 60,
        child: ListView(
          controller: _sTabController,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: List.generate(keyList.length, (index) {
            return Wrap(
              children: [
                Container(
                  key: keyList.elementAt(index),
                  color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10,bottom: 10,left: 40,right: 40),
                      child: Text(
                        'Text $index',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21),
                      )),
                )
              ],
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output

I/flutter ( 5864): keyItemRenderBox dx {0}: 0.0

I/flutter ( 5864): keyItemRenderBox dx {1}: 77.0

I/flutter ( 5864): keyItemRenderBox dx {2}: 154.0

I/flutter ( 5864): keyItemRenderBox dx {3}: 231.0

I/flutter ( 5864): keyItemRenderBox dx {4}: 308.0

I/flutter ( 5864): keyItemRenderBox dx {5}: 385.0

I/flutter ( 5864): keyItemRenderBox dx {6}: 462.0

I/flutter ( 5864): keyItemRenderBox dx {7}: 539.0

I/flutter ( 5864): keyItemRenderBox dx {8}: 616.0

════════ Exception caught by scheduler library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════

The method 'findRenderObject' was called on null.

Receiver: null

Tried calling: findRenderObject()

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Also when try with below

```
padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10,bottom: 10,left: 40,right: 40),
```

Output

---

I/flutter ( 7007): keyItemRenderBox dx {0}: 0.0

I/flutter ( 7007): keyItemRenderBox dx {1}: 137.0

I/flutter ( 7007): keyItemRenderBox dx {2}: 274.0

I/flutter ( 7007): keyItemRenderBox dx {3}: 411.0

I/flutter ( 7007): keyItemRenderBox dx {4}: 548.0

════════ Exception caught by scheduler library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════

The method 'findRenderObject' was called on null.

Receiver: null

Tried calling: findRenderObject()

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

There possible to fetch findRenderObject() of all horizontal list item?

Comment: yes there all visible and scroll able but need to renderbox for all item but fetching null some after item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the item (9th onwards) is not yet rendered. ListView does the lazy rendering.

So if you want to achieve this, you need to you "SingleChildScrollView" with axis as "Axis.horizontal".